# Why does a difference of time.perf_counter slows down over time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a school project and have to read values from an accelerometer plugged into an arduino over an interval of time and write it to a csv file.
To increase the accuraccy of the reading I'm placing all values transmitted by the captor in a list, doing the mean once every [X] seconds and then stocking those values into a final list before writing them to my csv file.
To do that I'm using the time.perf_counter() to be able to precisely know exactly when i'm collecting those values.

When launching a test for 1000 values over 1s, the first values are fine except a little drift but that doesn't bother me that much. However, after the 40 value, the reading are spaced from 0.01s instead of 0.001s (which would be expected)

Not sure if it is of any value but i'm running python 3.7 on Pycharm.

```
import serial
import time
import csv
import numpy as np
ser = serial.Serial('COM5',9600)
while True:
    print("Initialisation", end="")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    for x in range(0,3):
        print(".", end="")
        time.sleep(0.3)
    entre=input('\nPress S to begin input or Q to quit')
    if entre=='S':
        del entre                                         #On supprime entre pour boucle infinie
        X=[]
        Y=[]
        Z=[]
        total=[]

        temps_de_mesure=1
        nombre_de_mesure = 1000
        intervalle_entre_2_mesures = temps_de_mesure/nombre_de_mesure    #Recupèrer toutes les valeurs
        t0 = time.perf_counter()
        for x in range(0, nombre_de_mesure):
            t_repeat = time.perf_counter()
            liste_temporaire = [[], [], []]

            while time.perf_counter()-t_repeat < 0.001:
                temp = str(ser.readline())
                temp = temp[2:-5]
                temp = temp.split(';')
                liste_temporaire[0].append(int(temp[0]))
                liste_temporaire[1].append(int(temp[1]))
                liste_temporaire[2].append(int(temp[2]))

            t_moyenne=time.perf_counter()-t0
            x_moyenne=np.mean(liste_temporaire[0])
            y_moyenne=np.mean(liste_temporaire[1])
            z_moyenne=np.mean(liste_temporaire[2])

            total.append([t_moyenne,x_moyenne,y_moyenne,z_moyenne])


        print(total) #affichage résultat

        with open('acquision.csv','w', newline='') as csvFile:         #Création d'un fichier csv acquisition avec les valeurs
            writer=csv.writer(csvFile)
            writer.writerows(total)
        csvFile.close()

    elif entre=='Q':break

ser.close()
```